# LeadConvert.setOverwriteLeadSource not behaving as expected?

Tags: apex, leads, lead-conversion

I'm working on a custom lead conversion application, and one of my requirements is to overwrite existing contact data (email, phone, custom fields) with the data in the lead object when converting a lead into an existing contact. From what I have read, this should be possible by changing the 'setOverwriteLeadSource' setting to true. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm)

However, setting this flag to true does not seem to work. When I convert a lead to a contact, the existing contact data does not get overwritten. I have double-, triple-, quadruple-checked our field mappings, tried to overwrite different fields, etc., and I still can't seem to get the overwrite feature to work. Is there something I'm missing here? Maybe another flag I need to set? Some other nuance I'm not aware of? Any help you can provide is appreciated.

For reference, my code:

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
lc.setOverwriteLeadSource(true);
lc.setAccountId(contact.AccountId);
lc.setContactId(contact.Id);

LeadStatus status = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true];
lc.setConvertedStatus(status.MasterLabel);
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
```

Comment: that flag doesn't do what you want -- it only permits smashing of the LeadSource field on the target objects; no other fields